# PostgreSQL: nested loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, plpgsql

Is it possible to have a loop within another loop? (nested loops) in postgres. Something similar to below:

```
WHILE rowCounter < totalRows LOOP

    FETCH NEXT FROM retailerIdCursor INTO retailerID;

    --FOR i IN 1..8 LOOP
    --WHILE i < 8 LOOP
    LOOP
        UPDATE sales_fact
        SET retailer_id = retailerID
        WHERE sales_id = rowCounter;

        EXIT WHEN i > 8;
    END LOOP;

    rowCounter = 1+ rowCounter;

END LOOP;
```

Comment: Why oh why would you want to do anything like this? This looks like it should be trivial to rewrite as a single set-based `UPDATE`.

Comment: Yes it's possible, no problem at all. But why do you think you need it? Nested loops are slow, very slow.

Comment: Yeah probably the query may be slow. But this is a one time process. I am creating a test dataset and for that only I need this to work. I tried, but when I check the desired change has not happened in the database.

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see why you cannot just write

```
UPDATE sales_fact
   SET retailer_id = retailerID
WHERE sales_id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

as Frank has suggested.

Depending on the statement that selects the retailerId, you might not even need the outer loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at postgresql documentation. 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I actually went through the documentation too. But my function with the nested loops doesn't give me the desired result. Thanks again.

Comment: The nested loop is useless, just use a simple `WHERE sales_id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)`. Now you only need a single UPDATE for 8 different conditions.